# In Unreal, how can I access the instruction count of a material from a plugin?

Tags: c++, game-development, unreal-engine4

I'm working on an editor plugin in Unreal where I need to access the instruction counts of materials.  I found where this is normally done for the editor in the engine's code.

MaterialStatsCommon.h in \Engine\Source\Editor\MaterialEditor\Public\ has the class FMaterialStatsUtils which includes this.

```
/** class used for various stats utilities */
class FMaterialStatsUtils
{
public:
    MATERIALEDITOR_API static void ExtractMatertialStatsInfo(struct FShaderStatsInfo& OutInfo, const FMaterialResource* Target);
};
```

Everything here is public, but that FShaderStatsInfo is declared in MaterialStats.h, which is in the same module but in a private folder.

After including the module in my plugin, using this function is easy enough.  That is, as long as I forward declare FShaderStatsInfo.  However, then when I actually try to access anything FShaderStatsInfo from my plugin, I can't because it says the type is incomplete and I'm not able to actually include MaterialStats.h.

Is there anyway around this or a different way to access the same thing on materials?

Where I'm getting stuck:

```
#include "MaterialStatsCommon.h"

struct FShaderStatsInfo;

void MyEditorBPLibraryName::GetMaterialStatsInfo(UMaterial* Material, int32 BasePassShaderInstructionCount, int32 VertexShaderInstructionCount, int32 TextureSampleCount)
{
    if (Material == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }
    FShaderStatsInfo* OutInfo = nullptr;
    FMaterialStatsUtils::ExtractMatertialStatsInfo(*OutInfo, Material->GetMaterialResource(ERHIFeatureLevel::SM5, EMaterialQualityLevel::Num));
    //OutInfo-> I needed ShaderInstructionCount from this struct, but can't access anything in it

    return;
}
```

and the struct I need to use in MaterialStats.h:

```
#include "MaterialStatsCommon.h"
#include "UObject/GCObject.h"

/** structure used to store various statistics extracted from compiled shaders */
struct FShaderStatsInfo
{
    struct FContent
    {
        FString StrDescription;
        FString StrDescriptionLong;
    };

    TMap<ERepresentativeShader, FContent> ShaderInstructionCount;
    FContent SamplersCount;
    FContent InterpolatorsCount;
    FContent TextureSampleCount;
    FContent VirtualTextureLookupCount;
    FString StrShaderErrors;

    void Reset()
    {
        ShaderInstructionCount.Empty();

        SamplersCount.StrDescription = TEXT("Compiling...");
        SamplersCount.StrDescriptionLong = TEXT("Compiling...");

        InterpolatorsCount.StrDescription = TEXT("Compiling...");
        InterpolatorsCount.StrDescriptionLong = TEXT("Compiling...");

        TextureSampleCount.StrDescription = TEXT("Compiling...");
        TextureSampleCount.StrDescriptionLong = TEXT("Compiling...");

        VirtualTextureLookupCount.StrDescription = TEXT("Compiling...");
        VirtualTextureLookupCount.StrDescriptionLong = TEXT("Compiling...");
        
        StrShaderErrors.Empty();
    }

    void Empty()
    {
        ShaderInstructionCount.Empty();

        SamplersCount.StrDescription.Empty();
        SamplersCount.StrDescriptionLong.Empty();

        InterpolatorsCount.StrDescription.Empty();
        InterpolatorsCount.StrDescriptionLong.Empty();
        
        TextureSampleCount.StrDescription.Empty();
        TextureSampleCount.StrDescriptionLong.Empty();

        VirtualTextureLookupCount.StrDescription.Empty();
        VirtualTextureLookupCount.StrDescriptionLong.Empty();

        StrShaderErrors.Empty();
    }

    bool HasErrors()
    {
        return !StrShaderErrors.IsEmpty();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For the stats themselves, you can use:

```
FMaterialStatistics Stats = UMaterialEditingLibrary::GetStatistics(_YourMaterialInterfaceObject_);
```